# what is flask-sqlalchemy where in clause query syntax?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I`m using flask-sqlalchemy and my problem is where in clause like:

```
select * from table_1 where id in (1,2,3,5)
OR
select * from table_1 where field_1_id in (select id from table_2 where .... )
```

and get_or_create like peewee orm

```
Object.get_or_create(.......)
```

how can i generate this sentences with flask-sqlalchemy ?

Comment: Did you try SQLAlchemy's Documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [**.in_** clause](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.in_) in sqlalchemy

```
result = db_session.query(table_1).filter(table_1.id.in_((1,2,3,5))).all()
```

**Note**: here am assuming table_1 is your model

Comment: where does this line of code go in the actual flask app? in the `models` or `view` code ?

Comment: depends on your implementation, but generally will be in views

Comment: more specifically where in a `view` like below? 

`class Table_AView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(AuctionTransactions)
    label_columns = {'Field_A':'A'}
    list_columns = ['Field_A']`

Comment: You can also provide a list to the `in_()` method. like `table_1.id.in_([1,2,3])`

Answer (score 1):

Alternate you can also use the following syntax:

```
result = TableName.query.filter(TableName.id.in_([1,2,3]))
```

**Note:** I am using flask-sqlalchemy.